# GitHub workflow: Should each developer have their own fork?

Tags: git, github

Our team is using GitHub for the first time. We set it up so that we can use `pull requests` as a way to do code reviews.

1. There is a group organization that everyone has rights to, and which contains the canonical repo.
2. Each developer `forked` the group repo and pushes changes to their `fork`.
3. Developers submit a `pull request` to the group repo when ready, and another developer reviews the code and then `pulls` it in.

Is this a reasonable work flow? My concern is that the forked repos don't automatically get updated when the group repo gets updated. Would it be better if everyone contributed directly to the group repo? If so, is there a way to use GitHub for convenient code reviews?

Comment: How about a branch for each developer, with one person responsible for merging those in after a code review?

Comment: This _is_ a reasonable workflow, but it doesn't matter what we think. Does it work for your team? If your team is small, it might make sense to not use forks and instead just use feature branches. You can still Pull Request branches.

Comment: Ok, I'm going to have to look into using branches, it sounds like that may simplify things in terms of push/pull actions. Would each developer maintain a branch, or would it make sense to create a branch for each change and delete the branch when it gets pulled?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each developer *always* has their own fork; every clone is a full fork. Forking the repo in Github as well means that every dev has *two* forks, with a lot of redundant pushing and pulling between their local fork and their Github fork.

There's very little value to this. Forks on Github are great when you expect to have multiple developers pushing and pulling, or when you don't have the ability to simply push a branch to the original repo and open a pull request.

Within a single Github repository, you can open pull requests for branches. Typically your developers would work locally on a feature branch, push that branch to the shared remote, and then open a Github pull request to merge that branch into master.

Comment: Ah, I never thought of it that way. However, I haven't seen a way to send a pull request from a local cloned version of a repo. The main thing we wanted is the ability to use pull requests as a code-review system.

Comment: @brentonstrine you can create pull requests for branches of a single repo. A fork is not needed.

Comment: Disagree with this answer. Real company scenarios keeping the main repo clean became a nightmare. People leave the branch open for a long time if not so forever, forget test branches. Long term you don't know what is really something important and what is not. If everyone have their on fork on GH at least the personal mess don't impact the company main repo

Comment: Bingo, this ^.  Branches in the main "upstream" repo for longer running feature development (and possibly every feature aside of small bug fixes), but always develop against your own fork first, push to your fork whenever you want, pull request from branch on your fork to branch in upstream. Gives you many layers of recovery in case you screw something up, with only one extra step